# How to write CLLocation's GPS information into UIImage using PHPhotoKit?

Tags: ios, image, gps, location

Is there any method to write GPS info into one image? 
for example, I want to develop a camera app that can take photos with location information.
Can I use PhotoKit related methods or some other methods such as ImageIO?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean add watermark to a image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add location information to your image like this

```
let locationCordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, long)
let currentDate = NSDate()
let imageLocation = CLLocation(coordinate: locationCordinate, altitude: 0.0, horizontalAccuracy: 0.0, verticalAccuracy: 0.0, timestamp: currentDate)
```

After this you can add this location to your image like this

```
PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({

      let assetLocationChangeRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest(forAsset: lastImageAsset)
      assetLocationChangeRequest.location = imageLocation

      }, completionHandler: {
            (success:Bool, error:NSError?) -> Void in

            if (success) {
                print("Succesfully saved location to image")
            } else {
                print("Failed to save with Error : \(error!)")
                }
        })
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works !!! This should be assetLocationChangeRequest.location = imageLocation.

Answer (score 0):

Update for Swift 5 / Xcode 14:

```swift
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges ({
    let assetLocationChangeRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest(for: lastImageAsset)
    assetLocationChangeRequest.location = imageLocation
}) { success, error in
    if (success) {
        
        print("Succesfully saved location to image")
    } else {
        print("Failed to save with Error : \(error!)")
    }
}
```